# Is there any need to change bundle identifier for distributing education IOS application under Volume Purchase Program

Tags: ios, apple-vpp

We want to distribute our education IOS application under Volume purchase Program. The application is already in Appstore. So is it necessary to change the bundle identifier and name of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
You don't need to do anything specific or even resubmit the app. You can apply to the program in https://itunesconnect.apple.com in your application details.

[image]

More info:

https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/volume-purchase-program/

Comment: Our application is available in Appstore. We enabled some features and we need to submit this version. But we are planning to submit this new version under VPP keeping the old version as it is.

Comment: To submit the new application you have to have new bundle identifier. You can just append something at the end, like if your app id was `com.example.app` then you can have the new app as `com.example.app.feature`.
Having a separate application for VVP is a good choice especially if you had in-app purchases within. VPP discounts do not apply on these.
Also it is worth noting that regular users still will be able to purchase your VPP application for full price.